# ServiceStack select projection not working as expected

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, servicestack

ServiceStack select projection not working as expected

Here is example

```
var q = db.From<Product>()
            .Select<Product>(p=>
                new
                {                     
                    Name = p.Name,
                    Price = p.Price,                     
                    ExtraVATColumn= 5*8
                }
               );
             return db.Select<object>(q);
```

It returns

> [{"Name":"Book","Price":1103.46,"40":40}]

instead of

> [{"Name":"Book","Price":1103.46,"ExtraVATColumn":40}]

In standard ASP.NET Web Api application Linq Select projection works as expected but not in ServiceStack Api.

Can someone give explanation ?

Comment: `Select<Product>` is not an existing overload. Please show actual code that compiles.

Answer (score 1):

`5*8 = 40`

It uses the `Product` property names i.e **p.Name, p.Price** as the keys in your JSON result. In the case of `ExtraVATColumn`, no property/variable was supplied in your Linq. So instead, the value `40` was used as the name of the key upon serialization.